# Is using taxonomies the way to go here or would custom post types be better?

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy, users

I to create a site that will let subscribers select items from a list, say of books or DVDs - essentially building a collection that they could then add additional info, e.g. price paid, where purchased, etc. Then if a post is later added that is related to that item, the user would be notified.

My thoughts are to use specific taxonomies for the list of items. And then figure out how I can let users check off their interest in these specific taxonomies and add the additional info. Then essentially subscribe them to posts related to only the taxonomies they are interested in.

Am I off base in my thinking? Is there a better way to do what I am talking about?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do it that way.

My thoughts: Have same post names for both the list and actual posts. Store in the user profile the list of slugs/titles of their interest, and then on real post publish, cross check which user has that post title/slug stored in their interest and notify them about it.